# Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

Tags: java, sockets

I am trying make a socket conection and send a file inside my windows 7 with netbeans but I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:69)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:337)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:198)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:180)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:157)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
    at socket.TCPclient.main(TCPclient.java:22)
Java Result: 1
```

This is my server class:

```
package socket;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class TCPserver {
  public static void main (String [] args ) throws IOException {
    // create socket
    ServerSocket servsock = new ServerSocket(13267);
    while (true) {
      System.out.println("Waiting...");

      Socket sock = servsock.accept();
      System.out.println("Accepted connection : " + sock);

      // sendfile
      File myFile = new File ("source.pdf");
      byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [(int)myFile.length()];
      FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
      BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
      bis.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
      OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();
      System.out.println("Sending...");
      os.write(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
      os.flush();
      sock.close();
      }
    }
}
```

and this is my client class:

```
package socket;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class TCPclient{
  public static void main (String [] args ) throws IOException {
    int filesize=6022386; // filesize temporary hardcoded

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int bytesRead;
    int current = 0;
    // localhost for testing
    Socket sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1",13267);
    System.out.println("Connecting...");

    // receive file
    byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [filesize];
    InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("source-copy.pdf");
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
    bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
    current = bytesRead;

    // thanks to A. Cádiz for the bug fix
    do {
       bytesRead =
          is.read(mybytearray, current, (mybytearray.length-current));
       if(bytesRead >= 0) current += bytesRead;
    } while(bytesRead > -1);

    bos.write(mybytearray, 0 , current);
    bos.flush();
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(end-start);
    bos.close();
    sock.close();
  }
}
```

**How can I fix this problem, Thank you?**

Comment: I'm newbie with java. How can I run the server inside netbeans? Thank you!

Comment: The `connection refused` error could mean that the server **isn't** listening at that port yet, or could also mean that the **firewall** is preventing connections to it. You need to start the server and then run the client. Also, add an exception in the Windows Firewall.

Comment: Where did you get port? randomly? try to `ServerSocket servsock = new ServerSocket(0);` to generate free port. You can check it by using `servsock.getLocalPort()`

Comment: @MaximShoustin The server isn't throwing the error here. The client is. Also, if he generates a random port, the client will also have to be modified accordingly.

Comment: Start/execute/run (whatever term you are familiar with) the server class first, then start the client class.

Comment: I wish this question was still open. `This question is unlikely to help any future visitors` - that is rubbish. It's extremely relevant (look at the number of views - most likely people getting the same error)