# Java Connection refused: connect exception with Eclipse behind firewall

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm

I'm at a loss on how to fix this or what setting to update. Here is the error I'm getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:649)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:275)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:371)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1103)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:997)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:449)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:434)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:181)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:170)
at final_project.GetHyperlinks.main(GetHyperlinks.java:17)
```

and here is the code I'm attempting to run:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class GetHyperlinks {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack" , "true");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.8.0_25/jre/lib/security/cacerts");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","changeit");
    String url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835505";

    Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

    String question = document.select("#question .post-text").text();
    System.out.println("Question: " + question);

    Elements answerers = document.select("#answers .user-details a");
    for (Element answerer : answerers) {
        System.out.println("Answerer: " + answerer.text());
    }
}
}
```

I've updated the keystore, set _JAVA_OPTIONS env variable. My HTTP_PROXY env variables are correct. Is there another place within eclipse or the jvm that I need to set the proxy info?

Comment: Could you look this question; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13777826/exception-in-thread-main-java-net-connectexception-connection-refused-connec

Comment: @SemihEker thanks, I already did. That's a different problem. I think in that one they're running a server. I'm not, I'm just trying to grab html from a website.

Answer (score 2):

I have used https.properties and connection successful:

```
public static void jsoupSimple()
{
    try
    {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.home"));
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));

        System.setProperty(
                "javax.net.ssl.trustStore",
                System.getProperty("java.home") + "/lib/security/cacerts"
        );

        System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "host");
        System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "port");

        String url = "https://ru.stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=java&sort=newest";

        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap();

        headers.put("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0");

        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).headers(headers).get();
        String html = doc.html();

        System.out.println(html);
    } catch (IOException ex)
    {
        Logger.getLogger(JsoupTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```